# VIrtualHost Options returns an index of the site folder

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I am not sure why this is happening as I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to Apache.  Below is a copy of my VirtualHost.

If this gives any extra help as to how to get it to work, I am trying to run a CakePHP site.  I know the site itself has no issues as I have another location I manage the code from and can get it running locally through Apache there.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/sites/sitename"
    ServerName dev.sitename.com
    ErrorLog "logs/sitename.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/sitename.com-access.log" common


    <directory "C:/sites/sitename">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

I am running this on Apache 2.0 and Win7sp1

**UPDATE**

I never found the real solution using the route I was on.  I downloaded a fresh copy of WAMP and was soon able to get everything up and running, no problem.

Comment: I am running this on Apache 2.0 and Win7sp1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to *prevent* apache from showing the directory listing, you need to *disable* `indexes`. Also, it's best to disable MultiViews as that will enable content-negotiating, which may produce unwanted side-effects

Change the options to;

```
 Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Then, check that the `.htaccess` file is present inside your webroot (`C:/Sites/Sitename`), as that file is used to enable mod_rewrite

### Additional pointers/hints

First of all, make sure that the `DocumentRoot` is pointing to the right directory of your application;

The standard directory structure of CakePHP looks like this;

```
app
   /Config
   /Controllers
   /Views
   ......
   /webroot
lib
   /Cale
plugins
```

The `DocumentRoot` should point to your `app/webroot' directory, which contains all 'public' files.

Change the paths/directories in your virtual host to that directory and restart Apache.

If you're still getting a 403 error, change the URL you're visiting in your browser to this;

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php
```

If this *does* work, check if the `.htaccess` file is present in that directory and `mod_rewrite` is installed in your Apache.

Comment: @theJeztah The `-Indexes` brought me back to my original issue I was having....403 Forbidden.  I also see you removed `MultiViews`.  As I am unsure what this is, should I also remove it?  It does not fix the 403 Forbidden.

Comment: The 403 error is also shown if no 'index' file is present. I'll try to add some additional hints

Comment: I have tried pointing DocumentRoot directly to the app/webroot folder and it still gave me the 403 error.  I also put /index.php into the url and I accessed the direct file (just like when I had the directory index).

Comment: Yes, I actually realized I didn't have my mod_rewrite turned on but, I have since turned it on.  I am now receiving the following error.

`[Sun Apr 21 15:56:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by rule: C:/sites/sitename/app/webroot/`

When I go to /index.php I get a file output of the actual file rather than a server interpretation of that file.  Are there particular file/folder permissions in windows I need to grant to Apache for it to work?

Comment: Aparently, PHP (mod_php) isn't enabled in your apache configuration as well

Comment: Although in the end I did not use your answer, I wanted to give you credit for you persistence in helping me.  I am going to edit my question to provide the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, and glad to hear you managed to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer from "thaJetzah" (sorry, can't comment yet:) )

403 Forbidden is better than having the index of the folder, because now you can see the logs/sitename.com-error.log log and hopefully it tells you, why it gives 403.

Just to make sure: The index.php is in the folder "C:/sites/sitename"?

If you can't isolate the error like this, it would be great to post here the output of the error.log when you try to access the page and it gives you 403.

Comment: Thanks @M-z, I was out of town, added some additional tips to my 'answer'

Comment: `[Sun Apr 21 14:58:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by rule: C:/sites/sitename/app/webroot/`

`[Sun Apr 21 14:58:36 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by rule: C:/sites/sitename/`

Is what came up.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://blog.code4hire.com/2011/03/setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-apache-on-ubuntu-for-local-development/) If you are running Ubuntu.

Comment: Good suggestion, but based on the paths he is using (C:/sites/sitename) you could have understood he's running on Windows. (He also added it as a comment below the question: "I am running this on Apache 2.0 and Win7sp1"